# Regex positive lookbehind alternative for word wrap

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I'm using regex in JavaScript to split a long string and force a word wrap, but learned that some browsers (Safari in particular) don't support positive lookbehinds. Is there a more browser-friendly way to get the same result as this:

```js
  if (text.length > 45) {
    return text.split(/(?<=^(?:.{45})+)(?!$)/).join("\r\n");
  }
```

Comment: Try just `.replace(/.{45}(?!$)/g, '$&\r\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
return text.replace(/(.{45})(?!$)/g, "$1\r\n");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/lZkyjh/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{45}                    any character except \n (45 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: @bildungsroman Regex is working, but your code is wrong. Use ``const regex = new RegExp(`(.{${limit}})(?!$)`, "g");``